# How to use “grep -f file-with-patterns” in a pipe where “file-with-patterns” changes frequently?

Tags: linux, scripting, grep, pipe

I am trying to do dynamic logging of dropped firewall events whereby I can dynamically specify what events *not* to log.

I use:

```
logread -f | grep -v -f file-with-patterns >> logfile
```

in a script running in the background.

This works fine, it logs everything except those events that I don’t want to be logged by specifying patterns in the file “file-with-patterns”.

However, it appears that when I update the file “file-with-patterns”, grep does not re-read it.

After a change to the file “file-with-patterns” I need to kill and restart the scripts starting all of this which is a bit cumbersome.

Can this be made to work without restarting the script? For instance crontab rereads the crontab file automatically when it changes. Is there some feature in grep (or an equivalent utility) that works like that?

Tried changing the file-with-patterns, grep did not change its filtering.

Comment: I don't think there's any built-in option to `grep` to make it do this. But it's open source, and you're a programmer (since you're posting on SO), so feel free to add it.

Comment: Almost no tools work like that. Standard cron does not auto-reload files, this is a modern feature found in only some implementations. Traditionally you had to invoke a command to reload it (that's why you run `crontab -e` instead of your editor directly)

Comment: What's changing the pattern file?

Comment: @PaulHodges; when I detect a heavy portscan (by the volume of logged dropped packets from iptables) I update the patterns file so that such a portscan does not deplete the limited memory in this system (Linux router).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could replace `grep -v -f file-with-patterns` with something like this, untested, using any awk that supports `delete array` (which is all of them these days AFAIK):

```
awk -v exceptionsFile='file-with-patterns' '
    function readExceptions(    exception) {
        delete exceptions
        while ( (getline exception < exceptionsFile) > 0 ) {
            exceptions[exception]
        }
        close(exceptionsFile)
    }
    {
        readExceptions()
        for ( exception in exceptions ) {
            if ( $0 ~ exception ) {
                next
            }
        }
        print
    }
'
```

That will re-read the file of exceptions every time it receives a line of input before it processes that line of input by comparing it against every exception as a regexp.

You could, of course, introduce a counter so it only calls `readExceptions()` every N lines of input or do something else to reduce how often it's called but as long as your file of exceptions isn't massively long that function will run in the blink of an eye so it's probably fine to call it for every line of input.

By the way, there may be a much more efficient way to do the above (e.g. a hash lookup instead of a loop comparing regexps), depending on the contents of your exceptions file, the output of that `logread` tool and what you're really trying to match on - post a new question with sample input/output if you'd like help with that.

Comment: Nice solution, but I noticed there is some memory leak in this solution which causes the router to restart twice a day.

After 4 hours, the router lost 5kb memory, which was reclaimed immediately the moment I killed the script.

No idea why. Any suggestions what is causing the memory leak?

Comment: A program using memory doesn't necessarily mean it has a memory leak. The script creates an array from exceptions so the more exceptions in the input the larger the array has to be to hold themThat's by design, it's not a leak, but I've no idea if that's the "issue" you suspect of being a leak or not. Ask a new question with all relevant details if you suspect there is a memory leak.

Comment: Perhaps calling it a “leak” is too harsh, but in time - all the time running with the same exceptions file - it uses more and more memory until none is available and the router then restarts. I call it a leak since there is nothing in the awk script suggesting that memory usage grows. I read some comments that “delete” does not free memory. That could be it.

Comment: Ask a new question with a [mcve] we can use to reproduce the problem, the version of awk you're running, the OS, and all other relevant details so I or others can take a look.

Comment: FWIW I see [the release notes for gawk 5.1.0](https://www.mail-archive.com/info-gnu@gnu.org/msg02734.html) say "A number of memory leak issues have been fixed." so they do happen sometimes and whatever problem you're having may be fixed by upgrading your awk version.

Comment: Running version 3.1.8, so that might explain it. Thanks.

Comment: @Ernst assuming that's gawk 3.1.8 - yeah, that version is about [14 years out of date](https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/gawk/) and missing a ton of bug fixes and extremely useful functionality, we're currently on gawk 5.3.0.

Comment: Ed, I know. But the router I am running this on I can’t compile new versions for. The OpenWRT toolchain is not running properly. Thanks for the splendid solution however, learned a lot of awk trying it out.

Comment: I found a gawk 4.1.4 static mips binary that works great. No more memory leaks! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

**Simple method** would be to load the config on every line, I guess **performance would suffer** a bit. Something along these lines:

`logread -f | while read LINE; do echo "$LINE" | grep -v -f file-with-patterns; done`

For ease of (re)use a small prof of concept operator program could be made from the first example:

`sudo nano /usr/bin/¬`

Remember to make it executable:
`sudo chmod +x /usr/bin/¬`

```
#! /bin/bash

while read LINE; do echo "$LINE"; done | $@
```

Then you could run any command in place of grep like this:

`logread -f |¬ grep -v -f file-with-patterns`

**Better trick** would be to monitor file for changes and reload if any exist. One way to do this would be with the help of tool called inotifywait. Something along these lines:

`while inotifywait -e modify file-with-patterns; do logread -f | grep -v -f file-with-patterns; done`

Experiment a bit, if stuck reach out here in comments :)

Comment: `while read LINE; do echo "$LINE"` needs to be `while IFS= read -r line; do printf '%s\n' "$line"` for robustness and portability. Otherwise it'll mangle the input in various ways given various input values and/or versions of `echo` used and/or environment variable settings.

Comment: See [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice) for an explanation of the `while-read` changes.

Comment: @0074b60ae; interesting use of inotify, but alas, the OpenWRT clone that runs on this router uses an old OpenWRT version that does not come with the inotify executables and the build for this OpenWRT clone is so convoluted and partly closed source that I can't go that route.

Comment: `$*` should be `"$@"`. The former loses any quoting.